# Removing parts of an image that extend outside parent layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop (CS6), how do I get rid of an image protruding from it's frame as pointed to in the below image?

[image: Image protruding it's frame]

EDIT:

Including the layers:

[image]

Creating a shape (circle) layer so I can use clipping mask only works if it contains a fill. No fill doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi. How has this been constructed?  Can you show how your layers are arranged?  Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have added another screenshot including the layers. Multiple shape layers make up the yellow surround. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have frame and background image as a separate layer then do this:

Step 1 : Create a shape layer (Circle) - Place it has the bottom layer

Step 2 : Place the image on top of the Shape layer and Right Click(on Image layer) -> Click(Create Clipping Mask)

Step 3: Then place the frame layer in the top of the all layers, then adjust the shape layer for better output!

If you have frame and background image as a single layer then do this:

Step 1: Create a Shape Layer with the BG Color and place the layer above where you are pointing

Step 2: Use Quick Selection tool(W) and select the extra shape in front of the frame by the BG layer enabled

Step 3: Then press Delete by enabling Shape layer !

[image]

Hope this is your Requirement!

Please make sure to mention the layers too, so that we can able to provide better answers!

if the either of the options does not works then do:

Step 1 : group the all the layers of the frame which you want to fill and then duplicate the group, place the duplicated group back side of the image and then do clipping mask, reduce the opacity of the top group! it works

Comment: Really struggling with this but I almost got it working following your first set of steps but the clipping mask only seems to work when creating a circle shape layer with a fill - no fill it doesn't seem to work - and I'm obviously wanting to retain the image behind the shapes as best I can (i.e exactly how it is in your version). (I edited original question showing the layers as well). Thanks

Comment: @zigojacko cool! ok then, group the all the layers of the frame which you want to fill and then duplicate the group, place the duplicated group back side of the image and then do clipping mask, reduce the opacity of the top group!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a layer mask to fix it

I have tried to set up a similar minimal example below to give you an idea of how you could go about this. Please ignore my brush cursor as it isn't displaying properly using my screen capture software.

Anyway . . .

Add a layer mask to your "image" group. Then paint on the layer mask with the Brush Tool using black as the foreground colour. Whatever you paint on will be masked out.

[image]

Example